# early 2015 13 inch macbook air shuts off when disconnected to power

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

my macbook air shuts down 0-30 seconds after I unplug it from the magsafe. 
 the computer says it's at 90%, and charging; I did an SMC reset, ran apple diagnostics (no issues detected), cleaned the port, tried using a new magsafe cable, and the system report on the battery is as follows:

Model Information:

Serial Number:    D8651634CATF90JA9

Manufacturer:   SMP

Device Name:  bq20z451

Pack Lot Code:    0

PCB Lot Code: 0

Firmware Version: 511

Hardware Revision:    000a

Cell Revision:    1210

Charge Information:

Charge Remaining (mAh):   5735

Fully Charged:    No

Charging: Yes

Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   6441

Health Information:

Cycle Count:  478

Condition:    Normal

Battery Installed:    Yes

Amperage (mA):    283

Voltage (mV): 8226

The I/O board was replaced a few months ago, so I don't think thats the issue.

Comment: The key to this is to look at the Amperage.  Fully charged you're supposed to have roughly 6.44A.  Your current Amperage is .3A - not nearly enough to power your MBA.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your battery. I suggest bringing it to apple for more diagnostics.